# Encryption and Decryption failing while adding records

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, webforms

I am working with a simple program and now I got stuck with a problam that is encrypting and decrypting the password and storing them in the database. The logic I am working with is encrypting the password but it is not storing in the database, instead it is throwing an error showing below

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

**My Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from admin where USERNAME=@USERNAME and PASSWORD=@PASSWORD ", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('userName is already availables')</script>");

            }

            else
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                string strQuery = EncodePasswordToBase64("insert into admin( USERNAME,PASSWORD) values('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "')");
                connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

            }

            con1.Close();
        }
        public static string EncodePasswordToBase64(string password)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encData_byte = new byte[password.Length];
                encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
                string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
                return encodedData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Question is:** *What I am doing wrong here?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the complete query instead you should only encode the password

```
string strQuery = EncodePasswordToBase64("insert ....
```

It should be:

```
string strQuery = "insert into admin( USERNAME,PASSWORD) values('" + txtUserName.Text + 
                   "','" +  EncodePasswordToBase64(txtPassword.Text) + "')");
```

You should **use SqlParameter and make a Parameterized query** instead o string concatenation

```
string strQuery = "insert into admin( USERNAME,PASSWORD) values(@pUserName, @pPassword)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUserName", txtUserName.Text");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", EncodePasswordToBase64(txtPassword.Text))
```

Comment: @user2189723, if its a new problem you can ask a new question, this will help you get better answers

Comment: ,i have taged a new question and plz..., see to that and ans me soon habib...,the taged question is one more in decription